# How to find the state of a wrapped Component Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

```
  const wrapper = mount(
    <ContextProvider>
      <FreeformEquationQuestionPractice question={question} />
    </ContextProvider>
  )

  console.log('freeform state: ', wrapper.childAt(0).instance().state)
```

`FreeformEquationQuestionPractice` Component is wrapped in `Question Component`, `export default QuestionComponent(FreeformEquationQuestionPractice)`.

How to find the state of `FreeformEquationQuestionPractice` component? The above `console.log` statement prints the state for `QuestionComponent` not `FreeformEquationQuestionPractice` Component?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you used it incorrectly. It must be `.state([key]) => Any`. You can refer [here](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/state.html)

Your code might look like this:

```
const wrapper = mount(
  <FreeformEquationQuestionPractice question={question} />
);
    
console.log('freeform state: ', wrapper.state());
```